# Django ForeignKey reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

I have 2 models, A parent and child model. I am trying to call the child model from the parent model

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class ChildClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=child_class)
```

If i want to refer to the Parent class i know i can use child class

new=ChildClass.objects.all then new.parent.name will give me parent name

The problem comes when i want to call the child class through the ManyToOne relationship. I don't know how to build my queryset.

I haven't tried anything cos i have never faced this problem and i couldn't find answer about it here

Comment: I'm still not really following what you aim to achieve. What is the "input" the parameters, what is the expexted output?

Comment: Sir, i am trying to query the Parent model in a way i can get ChildClass model

Comment: A way i can get ChildClass name via the ManytoOne relationship

Comment: Edited my Question any help will be greatly appreciated sir

Comment: I'm a bit confused too...are you after `parent.child_class.all()`? You can access the reverse relationship using the related name.

Comment: Yeah something like this sir. I will try it now. I have been trying to solve this for 6 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `_set` magic that Django automatically adds to your `Parent` model. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/)

But, bear in mind this wont get just one child from your parent, because your parent might have **many** children.

However, in your case, something like this should give you all of the children of the parent.

```py
parent = Parent.objects.first()
children = parent.childclass_set.all()
```

Comment: YESSSSSSIRRRR! IT WORKED SIR!

Comment: Now i am able to access all the children of an instance of Parent model. But is it possible to access all the children of all the Parent instances in a single query?

Comment: Then you would probably have to go the opposite way, something like this `ChildClass.objects.filter(parent__in=parents)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance sir! All my Django classes never touched this relationship so i was really troubled! 02:53am here, i can finally sleep. Big appreciation to you sir!

Answer (score 0):

you can write a single query and it is the best way to optimize the sql code written by django. your case in the official documentation is described as "reverse foreignkey" and prefetch_related is used. In case you want to access from childclass and find the parent use select_related.

```
    children = Parent.objects.prefetch_related('childclass_set').all().values('name','name__name')
    print(children)
    print(children.query)
```

with select_related in one query

```
    parent = ChildClass.objects.select_related('parent').all().values('name','parent__name')
    print(parent)
    print(parent.query)
```

you can look at how django writes SQL in terminal, if that can help you to understand better.
I recommend you study and understand how select_related and prefetch_related work. In production They allow you not to slow down your views. You can find lots of examples and explanations by Googling